# How can I get the separate IP address of each DNS root-servers' mirrors in the world?

Tags: linux, dns, ip, dig

I want to get the separate IP of all the root-servers’ mirrors in the world. We know every mirror has two IP addresses. One is used to support the DNS service and the other is used as its own IP which marks it in the internet.

How can I get the latter? Can I get it with the `dig` command on Linux?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? AFAIK, the root servers have a single IPv4 and a single IPv6. The current list can be obtained from: https://www.internic.net/domain/named.root

Comment: I means that...one root-server has many mirrors, these mirrors each has its IPv4 or IPv6 or both. When we use DNS service, these mirrors IP is same to the certain root-server. But actually it has its own IP. Such as a is a mirror of A.root-server, when someone query A.root-server, he may get a as result. But a's IP is 123.5.0.12 actually. My question is that how can I get a's actual IP(123.5.0.12)? Thanks

Comment: @FedonKadifeli: The root servers are anycast – there are [multiple instances](https://root-servers.org/) of the same IP address around the world, depending on the route taken. There's no way for sysadmins to specify that they want to connect to "the Amsterdam 198.41.0.4" or "the London 198.41.0.4" – so for remote management, each instance must have a second, unique address (that is used only for admins and not published in the root zone).

Comment: uh,you means that I cannot get the IP address that is used only for admins? But dig has a command 'dig NODES.L.ROOT-SERVERS.ORG TXT +short +tcp | head -10',isn't it to get the list of these mirrors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each root operator independently decides whether to publish this information or not.

Some operators publish a list of nodes over the web, including each node's individual domain name:

- K root (RIPE): https://www.ripe.net/analyse/dns/k-root/application/api/nodes (JSON format)
- L root (ICANN): https://www.dns.icann.org/imrsmap/json/map.latest.yaml (YAML format)

Other operators do not appear to publish this information at all.

Comment: But some other root do not publish these information, is there any way I can get them?

Comment: You could ask them?

Comment: Serious? I likely have a try.Thanks!

Comment: I find a way to get it. Take an eye on https://atlas.ripe.net/results/maps/root-instances.